# I keep getting a unexpected select error in my snosql statement

Tags: select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I keep getting an unexpected select error as well as an unexpected ON error in rows 61 AND 64 in my snowsql statement.

Not sure why if anyone can help that would be great. I've added the portion of my snowsql statement below.

I'm trying to use a select statement within a where clause is there a way to do this?

```
AS select
t1.sunday_date,
t1.sunday_year_month,
t1.sunday_month,
t1.dc,
t1.source_sku,
t1.Product_Family,
t1.Product_type,
t1.Product_Subtype,
t1.Material,
t1.Color,
t1.Size,
t1.EOL_Date,
t1.NPI_Date,
t1.period_start,
t1.period_month,
IIF( t4.period_start < t1.sunday_date, iif(ISNULL(ta.actual_quantity), 0, ta.actual_quantity),
    IIF(ISNULL(tfc.SOPFCSTOVERRIDE ), iif(ISNULL(tf.Period_Start), 0, tf.dc_forecast) , tfc.SOPFCSTOVERRIDE 
)) AS forecast_updated,
iif(ISNULL(tf.Period_Start),t4.period_start,tf.Period_Start) AS period_start_forecast,
iif(ISNULL(ti.VALUATED_UNRESTRICTED_USE_STOCK), 0, ti.VALUATED_UNRESTRICTED_USE_STOCK)  AS inventory_quantity,
iif(ISNULL(ti.HCI_DS_KEYFIGURE_QUANTITY), 0, ti.HCI_DS_KEYFIGURE_QUANTITY)  AS in_transit_quantity,
iif(ISNULL(ti.planned_quantity), 0, ti.planned_quantity) AS inbound_quantity,
iif(ISNULL(tbac.backlog_ecomm ), 0, tbac.backlog_ecomm) + iif(ISNULL(tbac_sap.backlog_sap_open), 0, tbac_sap.backlog_sap_open)   AS backlog_quantity,
iif(ISNULL(ta.actual_quantity), 0, ta.actual_quantity) AS actual_quantity,
iif(ISNULL(tso.open_orders), 0, tso.open_orders) AS open_orders,
iif(ISNULL(tf.Period_Start), 0, tf.dc_forecast) AS forecast,
tfc.SOPFCSTOVERRIDE AS forecast_consumption,
iif(ISNULL(tpc.SHIP_DATE), 0, tpc.SHIP_DATE) AS production_current_week,
iif(ISNULL(tpc.SHIP_DATE), 0, tpc.SHIP_DATE) AS production_next_week,
NOW() AS updated_timestamp 

FROM ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( (

SELECT 
e.sunday_date,
e.sunday_month,
e.sunday_year_month,
d.dc,
c.SOURCE_SKU,
c.Product_Family,
c.Product_Type,
c.Product_Subtype,
c.Material,
c.Color,
c.Size,
c.EOL_Date,
c.NPI_Date,
b.period_start,
b.period_month


FROM 
(SELECT sunday_date, sunday_month, sunday_year_month FROM bas_report_date) AS e,
(SELECT distinct Week_Date AS period_start, DateSerial('445_Year','445_Month',1) AS period_month from inv_bas_445_Month_Alignment)  AS b, 
(SELECT source_sku AS source_sku, Product_Family, Product_Type, Product_Subtype, Material, Color, Size, EOL_Date, NPI_Date from inv_vw_product_dev )  AS c,
(SELECT dc AS dc FROM inv_bas_dc_site_lookup)  AS d

WHERE b.period_start >= 
( select
MIN(mt.Reference_Date )
FROM BAS_report_date tr
INNER JOIN inv_bas_445_Month_Alignment mt ON tr.sunday_month = DateSerial(mt.'445_Year',mt.'445_Month,1')
)

AND b.period_start <= DateAdd("ww", 26,e.sunday_date) 

) t1 

LEFT JOIN 
( 
    SELECT
    MATERIAL_NUMBER,
    CINT(LOCATION_NUMBER) AS Int_Location_ID,
    HCI_DS_KEYFIGURE_DATE,
    HCI_DS_KEYFIGURE_QUANTITY,
    PLANNED_QUANTITY,
    VALUATED_UNRESTRICTED_USE_STOCK

    FROM inv_vw_ibp_transit_inventorry_dev
) ti
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the [`DateSerial()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) function
(which is from VBA / MS Access / Excel from the Microsoft universe)
with [DATE_FROM_PARTS()](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html).

[DATE_FROM_PARTS()](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/date_from_parts.html) also supports the non-obvious functionality of `DateSerial()`:

`DateSerial(2020, 1, 1 - 1)` gets you New Year's Eve - the day before New Year's Day
`DATE_FROM_PARTS(2020, 1 - 1, 1 - 1)` is the month before the day before New Year's Day
`DATE_FROM_PARTS(y, m + 1, 0)` is End Of Month (EOM).
etc., etc.